# Is there a way to do this, Not to repeat?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I handle projects by code  **(PROYECT_A A00001)**

There are 3 tables **(SEGMENT SE00001,LABLE LA00001,STRONG ST00001)** that relate to a project, there may be repeated codes from these tables but they belong only to a project

**Is there any way to not repeat the fields?**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROYECT_A](
    [PROYECT_A] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CODE_A]  AS ('A'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[PROYECT_A],(0)),(5))),
    [STATUS] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CREATION_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CODE_A] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SEGMENT](
    [ID_SEGMENT] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CODE_SE]  AS ('SE'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID_SEGMENT],(0)),(5))),
    [NAME] [varchar](20),
    [POWW] [varchar](20),
    [SQWE] [varchar](20),
    [DATESTART] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DATESTART] [datetime] NOT NULL
    [CODE_A] [varchar](20)
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LABLE](
    [ID_LABLE] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CODE_LA]  AS ('LA'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID_LABLE],(0)),(5))),
    [NAME] [varchar](20),
    [POWW] [varchar](20),
    [SQWE] [varchar](20),
    [DATESTART] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DATESTART] [datetime] NOT NULL
    [CODE_A] [varchar](20)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STRONG](
    [ID_STRONG] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CODE_ST]  AS ('ST'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID_STRONG],(0)),(5))),
    [NAME] [varchar](20),
    [POWW] [varchar](20),
    [SQWE] [varchar](20),
    [DATESTART] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DATESTART] [datetime] NOT NULL
    [CODE_A] [varchar](20)
GO
```

Comment: Which fields hold the 'repeated codes'? Please post some sample and indicate which data is the problem

Comment: Hi Martin--Welcome to Stack Overflow! At this point, I'm not sure what you're asking. If the issue is with the data, please post what you're currently seeing, and what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

create a single table with `Type` column to differentiate the records whether it belongs to `SEGMENT`,`LABLE` or `STRONG`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SEGMENT](
    [ID_SEGMENT] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Type] as Varchar(15) -- Here `SEGMENT`,`LABLE` or `STRONG`
    [CODE_SE]  AS (case type 
                     when 'Segment' then 'SE' 
                     when 'LABLE' then 'LA' 
                     else 'ST' 
                   end +right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID_SEGMENT],(0)),(5))),
    [NAME] [varchar](20),
    [POWW] [varchar](20),
    [SQWE] [varchar](20),
    [DATESTART] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DATESTART] [datetime] NOT NULL
    [CODE_A] [varchar](20)
    )
```

Comment: The only issue i have is the insert needs to also guarantee only those values are ever entered in the source tables